# ¿Qué pasa si un usuario se equivoca dando recompensa a su pregunta?

Tags: discusión, recompensas

No sé si esto ha ocurrido antes.

En la pregunta:  [Error en añadir descuentos individuales en cada item](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/567980/29967) el usuario ha otorgado una jugosa recompensa.

Por algunos comentarios en esa pregunta, conversación en el chat y [una posterior pregunta que OP abrió y luego borró](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/568952/29967), parece que el problema planteado en la pregunta está a otro nivel, por lo que es posible que una respuesta no resuelva su problema.

¿En casos como ese, puede un moderador intervenir para dejar sin efecto la recompensa y OP no pierda esos puntos?

Si esto es posible, ¿cómo se debe proceder?

Comment: No. no es posible, y esta bien aclarado en la ayuda...

Comment: Yo entiendo por error al dar una recompensa como que nunca fue la intención del OP en generar esta. Pero este no parece ser el caso, el deliberadamente ofrece una recompensa por una pregunta que puede o no ser contestada. Ahora si una pregunta puede o no ser contestada es debatible, quizás yo no la entiendo y está fuera de mis capacidades, pero para otra persona puede ser clara como el agua. Finalmente quien juzga la respuesta es el mismo OP y nadie más

Comment: Si se permitiera, habria muchos que ofrecerian una recompensa y luego se "arrepentirian" al ultimo dia de estas y pedirian su reputación devuelta. Seria injusto. Una mala forma de ganar atención gratis.

Comment: Podemos revertir la recompensa, pero no la atencion recibida ni las esperanzas de ganar reputación de los que respondieron.

Comment: Tienen ustedes toda la razón, no había pensando en ninguno de los valiosos argumentos en cada uno de sus comentarios.

Comment: No hay que dar importancia a puntos y medallitas. Son zanahorias sin valor.

Comment: @fedorqui sí, esa respuesta y los comentarios aquí han aclarado mi duda. Gracias.

Comment: @CandidMoe tienen valor en cuanto a privilegios dentro del sitio. Pero, sea cual sea la verdad, hay gente que busca inflar su reputacion como sea (tal vez quieren poder iniciar recompensas? Tal vez creen que ganaran algo mas?

Comment: @DanteS. El único privilegio es el chat, que requiere muy pocos puntos. El resto es trabajo gratis.

Comment: @CandidMoe trabajar aqui gratis es un privilegio c:

Comment: De cualquier modo. Se nota que los que quieren inflar su reputacion no lo saben

Comment: Acabo de ver tu pregunta, esto me ha sucedido, desgraciadamente si no se asigna la recompensa esta se pierde.

Comment: En esa pregunta me ofreció darme la recompensa por la ayuda y atención prestada, pero es que no tenia ningún sentido porque realmente no entendí nada de lo que pretendía realmente con la pregunta, pues iba de un lado a otro expresando cosas y solucionándolas el mismo, y no entendía mis preguntas tampoco... más bien le hice de Pepito Grillo, je, y me negé a la recompensa y a poner una respuesta (tampoco sabia que poner que pudiera ayudar a nadie, je) y le dije que la pusiera el la respuesta, pero veo que no lo hizo tampoco.

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿qué significa que *se pierde*? ¿Nadie la recibe y quien otorga la recompensa se ve descontando de esos puntos?

Comment: @CandidMoe creo que pasado un tiempo aquí ya no se da tanta importancia a puntos o medallas, aunque puede haber percepciones diversas al respecto porque cada persona es distinta y le mueven intereses distintos. Yo lo que más valoro del sitio es que ayuda a aprender, que puedes ayudar a otros y puedes ser ayudado también en ciertos casos cuando no encuentras salida en algún código. Antes yo solía preguntar en el sitio en inglés, porque entiendo que hay mejores programadores allí, pero he notado que con el tiempo reina la indiferencia en aquel sitio, espero que no ocurra también en español.

Comment: @masterguru yo tampoco llegué a entender el problema el cual, según mi opinión, no era tan enrevesado y había venido a serlo por un error en otra parte, quizá al diseñar el modelo de datos. Comenté sobre eso a OP pero creo que no entendió mi comentario. Se ve que había luchado mucho con ese código y no estaba dispuesto a replantearse todo de nuevo porque *casi* lo estaba resolviendo. El problema quizá volverá más tarde (si algo cambia en su modelo de datos o en otra parte). El gran peligro, si tengo razón, es que habrá creído resolver el problema, pero el problema real está en otra parte.

Comment: @A.Cedano exacto, si no asignas la recompensa se pierden de cualquier forma los puntos.